# RabbitMQ channel leak when bus was failed to start

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a problem with MassTransit (Using MassTransit 3.5.7 (via Nuget), RabbitMQ 3.6.10, Erlang 19.0)

Looks like that MassTransit not clear up RabbitMQ channels, when bus is failed to start.

Here is my test program

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using MassTransit;

namespace TestSubscriber
{
  class Program
  {
        static void Main()
        {
            IBusControl busControl = null;
            var failCount = 0;
            var busNotInitialised = true;

            //Keep RabbitMQ switched off for a few iterations of this loop, then switch it on.
            while (busNotInitialised)
            {
                busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(sbc =>
                {
                    var host = sbc.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), h =>
                    {
                        h.Username("guest");
                        h.Password("guest");
                    });

                    sbc.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "some_queue", endpoint =>
                    {
                        endpoint.Handler<string>(async context =>
                        {
                            await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Received: {context.Message}");
                        });
                    });
                });

                try
                {
                    busControl.Start();
                    busNotInitialised = false;            
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Attempt:{++failCount} failed.");

                    //wait some time
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                }
            }

            //At this point, using RabbitMq's management web page, you will see failCount + 1 channels.
            busControl.Stop();
            //At this point, using RabbitMq's management web page, you will see failCount channels.

            Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

It continuously tries to create a service bus that uses RabbitMQ. 
The program breaks out of the loop as soon as the service bus is created successfully.
After running the program for a couple of minutes (with stopped RabbitMQ) and stopping on a breakpoint, I can see a lot of worker threads (one for each failed service bus creation attempt).
After startup RabbitMQ, all of those "dangling" connect threads will connect to RabbitMQ.

If I try to shut down the bus, the latest connection ( that belongs to the bus that was successfully created), is closed. All of the other dangling connections are still connected to RabbitMQ.

Problem here is that those dangling threads, when connected, reads data from the queue which leads to data loss.

Is there any way to get around this problem?

Comment: RabbitMQ is the most reliable piece of infrastructure that exists. We are running it on single node in production for years, processing millions of messages per day. What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev , our problem in Masstransit behavior, not with RabbitMq. inI case of connection problems during starting service bus(for example) our app will retry. And in case of success starting there are extra open channel (from failed starting try), which reads data from the queue but cannot process it. And we can not shut this channel down from our app. That is our problem.

Comment: For me this is looking like solving non-existing problem. But it is just my own humble experience of running MT services using RabbitMQ with millions of messages consumed over years.